# SSL availability on Google Clould

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I understand SSL is a on GCloud is work-in-progress. Do you have any ideas when SSL feature will be available for Production or Beta use?

At the moment I am writing this, status is 'Alpha', invite only.

cheers
Leonardo

Comment: For appengine you can use it: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl. In compute engine you can setup you web server to use ssl.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However I would need for _compute_ and be able to create like this:

`gcloud compute ssl-certificates create www-ssl-cert --certificate
  CRT_FILE_PATH --private-key KEY_FILE_PATH`

and use in a Container VM, all automated via **deployment manager**

thanks 
Leonardo

Comment: You can build certs in the classic way for web servers: openssl is your friend :)

Comment: I have created already a self signed cert for testing purpose. But it is not possible to send it to Google cloud yet because it is not available. This question is exactly to ask the google team a timeline. Refer t this link: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/ssl-certificates.
If there is not plans to support any time soon, I will have to look at AWS or Heroku to support SSL.

This is what you get if you run the command mentioned in previous comment: `ERROR: (gcloud.compute) Invalid choice: 'ssl-certificates'.`

Comment: Use this form to request access to EAP program: https://docs.google.com/a/noovle.it/forms/d/1CsYMa4ZqnT-giMxiEQrWsgtIhLRelzz8xUoDVTUVgMI/viewform

Comment: You can star at App Engine Issue Tracker 10802 about 'SSL on naked domains' to get any updates.